# In R, is there a way to remove a common word from a vector of characters?

Tags: r

In `R`, I currently have a vector of characters such as:

```
character.vec
> "File1.mat"      "File2.mat"       "File3.mat"        "File4.mat"
```

I was wondering if there were any functions to call on `character.vec` so that I can get something like:

```
"File1"      "File2"       "File3"        "File4"
```

instead. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that you just want to strip off the file extensions, but I suspect your logic is something else.  What is your logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're after:

```
> sub("\\.mat", "", character.vec)
[1] "File1" "File2" "File3" "File4"
```

You need the \\ before the . to distinguish it from its use in regular expressions as matching any character (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/regex).

More generally, if you wanted to replace everything in a string from the last period to the end, you could use:

```
sub("\\.[^\\.]*?$", "", character.vec)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also a built in way for parsing filenames without extensions:

```
> library(tools) # in base R, shouldn't need to load
> test <- c("File1.mat","File2.mat","File3.mat","File4.mat") 
> tools::file_path_sans_ext(test)
[1] "File1" "File2" "File3" "File4"
```